# Multiple group by row extracting in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by

let me tell you my sample data structure first.

```
CREATE TABLE foobar (
  id int primary key,
  lastname varchar(100) not null,
  firstname varchar(100) not null,
  val1 int not null,
  val2 int not null
)
```

imagine sample entries like that:

```
1, Smith, Bob, 1, 3
2, Smith, Bob 2, 1
3, SMith, Allen , 3, 4
```

i.e. Firstname, Lastname are not distinct here

Now see the query:

```
select     lastname, firstname, avg(val1), avg(val2)
from       foobar
where      lastname = 'Smith'
group by   firstname
```

sample output:

```
1, Smith, Bob, 1.5 , 2
2, Smith, Allen , 3, 4
```

Now i want three different things.

```
1. get me all smith where avg(val1) is the biggest value of all
2. get me all smith where avg(val1) is the lowest value of all
```

sample:

```
1.  1.5 is smallest value therefore get me  Bob
2.   3 is the biggest value therefore get me Allen
```

I don't know how to do this efficiently. 
My approach was to save the min and max of avg() and then join into the same table on that value. But i fell like this is a bad solution.

Is there some efficient way?

Comment: What's the third thing? And any particular flavour of SQL?

Comment: can be ignored. so far i just wanna know the first name  of all smiths .

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT firstname FROM my_table WHERE lastname = 'smith';

Comment: ok i meant: i wanna know the first name of all smiths where their avg(val1) is the min of all avg(val1) of all smiths

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you mean biggest value of all.  By definition, an average will never be the largest value, but instead, the median of all?

If you mean to just return the largest and smallest entries in the table, use something like this:

```
select     lastname, firstname, max(val1), val2
from       foobar
where      lastname = 'Smith'
group by   firstname

select     lastname, firstname, min(val1), val2
from       foobar
where      lastname = 'Smith'
group by   firstname
```